# What does the ?. mean in C#?

Tags: c#, operators

From the project `Roslyn`, file `src\Compilers\CSharp\Portable\Syntax\CSharpSyntaxTree.cs` at line `446` there is:

```
using (var parser = new InternalSyntax.LanguageParser(lexer, oldTree?.GetRoot(), changes))
```

What is the `?.` there?

Does it check whatever oldTree is `null` and if it's not then it's running the `GetRoot` method, and if not then what it returns? This is my first assumption (Which might be wrong), but I can't get forward with it. (Confirm it, and/or answer the new question)

I googled `What is ?. C#` and nothing related came up, it is as if it ignored my `?.`(?)

Comment: It's the [null-propagating operator](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883), and yes it's kind of tricky to google for an operator only made of punctuation characters.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It could be [Null-Conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) from C# 6.0:

> The null-conditional operator conditionally checks for null before invoking the target method and any additional method within the call chain.

In your case, if `oldTree` is `null`,

```
oldTree?.GetRoot()
```

will return `null` instead of trying to call `GetRoot()` and throwing `NullReferenceException`.